# How can I add a choose folder property that shows in the IDE with the 3 dots

Tags: c#, user-controls

I would like to add a feature like the following to a custom control, but I am unsure how to do this :

[image]

How can I add a property to a custom usercontrol that shows up like this in the developer IDE (forcing a folder selection with browse [...] button) in c#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an "Editor" attribute to specify the editor of the property. Make sure you have a reference to System.Design.dll in your project.

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    [Editor(typeof(System.Windows.Forms.Design.FolderNameEditor), typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))]
    public string SelectedPath
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Comment: nice job.  thank you.   Now for the path itself, do you know if I can use something other than 'string' as `string` is more prone to user error when setting like  `UserControl1.SelectedPath = "foo"`

Comment: I don't think FolderNameEditor would work with a different type of object. I suggest that you have the setter for SelectedPath validate the string being passed in against whatever rules you have for the path, e.g. checking the characters against Path.GetInvalidPathChars(), using File.Exists(), matching against a regular expression, and so on.